# jinja2 form include won't work

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, jinja2

I'm making my first steps with flask and also jinja2. I have run through some examples but now i try to integrate flask-security and got stuck a bit.

I try to built a modal with an login-form, so I put up a div like this:

```
<div class="modal">
<h3>Login</h3>
<form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
    {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email) }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password) }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
    {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
    {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit) }}
</form>
```

That is the template code taken from the example provided by flask-security. Now i tried to wrap that in

```
{% extends layout.html %}
{% block loginModal %} ... {% endblock %}
```

and tried to invoke that in the layout.html by

```
{% block loginModal %}{% endblock %}
```

which now i learned is not the way, as the content is rendered and the layout.html only invoked.

Now i tried to put that code directly in the layout.html once by the include statement and as this didn't work i put it in directly.

I also added

```
{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
```

in the first line, which are macros provided by the flask-security package. but all i get is the error:

```
UndefinedError: 'login_user_form' is undefined (after a long traceback)
```

I'm totally stuck here, reading jinja2 docs on the website for about an hour now. How can i get this form to work?

**Update (I'm sorry, it is a late update):**

My layout.html which implements the base layout for all pages

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MyExample</title>
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/gumby.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class=page>
    <nav id="navbar-main-nav" class="navbar">
      <div class="row">
      <a class="toggle" gumby-trigger="#navbar-main-nav #main-nav" href="#"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
      <h1 class="four columns logo"><a href="/">Logo</a></h1>
      <nav class="five columns pull_right">
        <ul id="main-nav">
          <li><a href="/link1/"><span>Link1 </span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/link2/"><span>Link2</span><i class="icon-cog" title="Customize"></i></a></li>
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
    <li>Hello {{ current_user.name }}</li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('security.logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="#" class="switch" gumby-trigger="#modal1">Open Modal</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('security.register') }}">Register</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <div class="content">
      <a class="close switch" gumby-trigger="|#modal1"><i class="icon-cancel" /></i></a>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="ten columns centered">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="five columns">
                {% block loginModal %}{% endblock %}
              </div>
              <div class="five columns">
                 <!-- register Form -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script gumby-touch="js/libs/" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/libs/gumby.min.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My login.html

```
{% extends layout.html %}
{% block loginModal %}
{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
{% include "security/_messages.html" %}

   <h3>Login</h3>
   <form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
      {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email) }}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password) }}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
      {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
      {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit) }}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

In an abstract way I want to built something like a widget i can import and use in another template to implement such things only once, like the login form. Later i want to be able to implement lists, that can be placed in a siderbar on every page, without having it implemented on each page by itself. I found [Flask Plugable Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/) but I haven't found a good example to understand the proper usage.

**Update 2:**

This (updated) implementation renders no form at all, without any error. I think I may have misunderstood the use of blocks.

** Solution **

With help from Mark I found the template context processor very helpful as kind of injection of variables. For some it might be obvious: flask-security provides the Forms as import, therefore my code now looks like this:

```
from flask.ext.security import LoginForm, RegisterForm
...
@app.context_processor
def inject_userForms():
    return dict(login_user_form=LoginForm(), register_user_form=RegisterForm() )
```

I added the form directly into my layout.html which works well now. What does not work at all is the inclusion of the block. It works if I use *blockception*, using the login block within a content block.

Comment: What do you mean by "which now i learned is not the way, as the content is rendered and the layout.html only invoked"? As far as I'm concerned, the way that you have provided would be the correct way to do things. Perhaps you can provide the full source for how you attempted to use this method? Also, it looks like you're missing a closing `</div>` element in your form HTML, not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: So layout.html (which is often named base.html) builds my wireframe. and has an {% block body %}{% endblock %} which then renders the content. I also have an index.html which renders the body. I googled a lot and found several entries which say that if a block should render it has to be in the rendered template, in this case the index.html and not the layout.html/base.html. I try to put up a longer example.

Comment: I understand that, but what I'm saying is that I think you might have some error in how you set up the layout.html and the template which uses the layout.html. You say how you went about changing your files from what you've provided in the question, but without us seeing the actual results of your modifications, we're not sure if you actually made the modifications correctly. Please modify the question to provide us the version of the templates (both the layout.html and the child template) and then the HTML that it is outputting. Finally, tell us what you EXPECT it to output.

Comment: I have edited the original post with a example. What I expect to output is the login form within the layout.html in the way that on every page the modal can be used to login or register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is:

> UndefinedError: 'login_user_form' is undefined

This is coming from the template, which looks like this...

```
{% extends layout.html %}
{% block loginModal %}
{% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
{% include "security/_messages.html" %}

   <h3>Login</h3>
   <form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
      {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email) }}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password) }}
      {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
      {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
      {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit) }}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Therefore, you are referencing `login_user_form`, but Jinja2 is complaining that you haven't actually defined `login_user_form`. You typically define this when you are trying to call the function to render your template..

```
def my_view():
    # ...
    return render_template('login.html', login_user_form=login_user_form)
```

If you don't have the 'login_user_form' passed as an argument to render_template you will get the error.

If you are expecting `login_user_form` to be defined on the template context elsewhere in your application (such as in a [template context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#context-processors)), then ensure that that part of your application is indeed working.

Comment: As I read this, I found out that I have forgotten the Information, that in the updated example the form is simply not rendering without any error. I have updated my original post.

Comment: By again reading it: You are right, but where can i implement this view for the base html. As i am never calling it directly to be rendered by a route i don't have any idea how to implement unrouted implementations of the rendering. Actually this would help me a lot because it seems to be the key information in implementing reusable widgets.

Comment: I still don't think I understand your question. When it comes down to it, you can think of Jinja's uses of `extends` and `block` as simply ways to combine multiple templates together into one big template. Then, it will use the template context to figure out stuff like `login_user_form`. Whether you try to use `login_user_form` in the `layout.html` or the `login.html` page, `login_user_form` still needs to be in the context. You can supply that using an argument to `render_template`, or using template context processors (as I linked to in my answer).

Comment: Also, both in this question and in your bug report for Flask, you discussed a `base.html` and a `layout.html`. Are you sure you are not confusing them?

Comment: I think i am not familiar enough with jinja. I have a layout.html which is for the base layout. In the flask documentation this base file is often referred to as base.html. I know how to get the context into a routed site, but i can't find information on how to get the context into this base layout without loading it on every route.

Comment: i can't edit my last comment: I will work through the template context processors maybe i can find my answers there

Comment: So you were right: I read the linked documentation about template context processors. I also found out, that flask-security provides the base forms like the login form as import: `from flask.ext.security LoginForm`and then I can use it in a context processor like this `@app.context_processor
def inject_userForms(): return dict(login_user_form=LoginForm())`